# Importar pasta de trabalho de outra planilha para uma nova pasta de trabalho na planilha atual

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Utilizando o [exemplo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff194819.aspx) passado no MSDN da Microsoft, o seguinte erro é apresentado:

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

Código VBA:

```
Sub Principal()
    Dim PathName As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim TabName As String
    Dim ControlFile As String

    ' This macro will import a file into this workbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    PathName = Range("O7").Value
    Filename = Range("O8").Value
    TabName = Range("O9").Value
    ControlFile = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=PathName & Filename
    ActiveSheet.Name = TabName
    Sheets(TabName).Copy After:=Workbooks(ControlFile).Sheets(1)
    Windows(Filename).Activate
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Windows(ControlFile).Activate
End Sub
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está dando o erro? Qual linha? Você tem a aba 1 de sua planilha com o nome "Sheet1"?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema está nas informações inseridas na coluna "O": lendo as ações realizadas pelo código, tudo indica que a ação `Workbooks.Open` vai tentar abrir um `FileName:=` "C\Users\User\Desktopmodelo". Assim, sugiro as seguintes mudanças:

- Na célula "O1", adicione uma `\` (barra invertida) para separar o nome da pasta do nome do arquivo.
- Na célula "O2", indique a extensão do arquivo procurado, se `.xls`, `.xlsx` ou outro. A extensão também compõe o nome do arquivo.

O erro provavelmente foi causado por causa disso, pois a referência não existe. CAso o 'Depurador' esteja indicando erro em outra linha, avise!